# cURL post data in URL scope not form scope?

Tags: php, coldfusion

Trying to help out someone who is trying to access and API using PHP.  My code using ColdFusion works fine posting to the API, but we can't get the PHP to work.  In CF the code uses urlparams to send the data:

```
<cfhttp url="https://example.com/_api/proxyApi.cfc" method="post" result="httpResult" charset="UTF-8">
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="method" value="apiauth"/>
  <cfhttpparam type="url" name="argumentCollection" value="#jsData#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

A dump of the resulting call from the API shows the variables in the URL like this:
[image]

method = apiauth is the main authorization function, and then the json string in argumentCollection is passed to the correction function in the API by apiauth.

From PHP his curl is posting as form data, not URL and the API complains that the required information is missing because it's in the wrong scope.  I've been trying to figure out how to make curl use URL scope instead:

```
$curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_URL => $target_url,
     CURLOPT_POST => 1,
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 2,
     CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'method' => 'apiauth',
        'argumentCollection' => $json
     )
));
```

The same dump from the API shows the same data, but in the wrong scope:

[image]

It seems like if we can get the data in the right scope we'll make progress, but my PHP knowledge is dangerously limited.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an empty POST in your CF example.

`<cfhttpparam type="url"` is processed as a query string parameter, as in:

`https://example.com/_api/proxyApi.cfc?method=apiauth&argumentCollection=...`

Thus your dump of the URL scope (the key-value-paired query string) shows the data.

To put those parameters into your POST body, you would use:

`<cfhttpparam type="formfield"`

And then you FORM scope would show the data.

---

Your PHP cURL does the latter: it adds your parameters to the POST body.

If you want the cURL to work as your example CF code, do this instead:

```
// add the parameters to the URL's query string
// start with & instead of ?, if the URL already contains a query string, see comment below snippet
$target_url .= '?'.'method=apiauth'.'&'.'argumentCollection='.urlencode($json);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $target_url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 2,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true
));
```

no query string in `$target_url`:

```
$target_url  = 'https://example.com/_api/proxyApi.cfc';
$target_url .= '?'.'method=apiauth'.'&'.'argumentCollection='.urlencode($json);
```

query string in `$target_url`:

```
$target_url  = 'https://example.com/_api/proxyApi.cfc?p=';
$target_url .= '&'.'method=apiauth'.'&'.'argumentCollection='.urlencode($json);
```

---

On a side note: You probably don't want to send JSON via query string as the query string has a limit of about 2000 chars (depends on browser and webserver). If your JSON is complex, your query string will be truncated and mess everything up. Use the POST body for this instead.